# Unreal 4 Crashes When Player Touches NPC

Tags: unreal-engine4

So I'm doing a test program with the C++ use of Unreal 4 where I have a character that moves with the directional keys and I have an NPC character. I want to make it so when the player reaches the NPC's collision capsule, it shows a message saying "Hi, I'm Owen". But once the player does that, Unreal crashes and I'm exited out. I think it has to do with the NPC code I came up with, but I just don't see the issue. Could someone please help?

[image: Crash Report]
NPC.h

```
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "Components/SphereComponent.h"
#include "Engine/Canvas.h"
#include "Engine/Font.h"
#include "Engine/World.h"
#include "NPC.generated.h"



UCLASS()
class GOLDEGG_API ANPC : public ACharacter
{
GENERATED_BODY()


public:
// Sets default values for this character's properties
ANPC(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = NPCMessage)
    FString NpcMessage;

UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Collision)
    USphereComponent* ProxSphere;

UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent, Category = "Collision")
    void Prox(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor, 
UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp,
        int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& 
SweepResult);

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = NPCMessage)
    FString name;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = NPCMessage)
    UTexture2D* Face;

protected:
// Called when the game starts or when spawned
virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public:
// Called every frame
virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

// Called to bind functionality to input
virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* 
PlayerInputComponent) override;
};
```

NPC.cpp

```
#include "NPC.h"
#include "Engine/Canvas.h"
#include "Engine/Font.h"
#include "MyHUD.h"
#include "Avatar.h"



// Sets default values
ANPC::ANPC(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer) : 
Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
// Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to 
improve performance if you don't need it.
PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
ProxSphere = ObjectInitializer.CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent> 
(this, TEXT("Proximity Sphere"));
ProxSphere->AttachToComponent(RootComponent, 
FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepWorldTransform);
ProxSphere->SetSphereRadius(150.0f);
ProxSphere->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &ANPC::Prox);
NpcMessage = "Hi, I'm Owen";

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void ANPC::BeginPlay()
{
Super::BeginPlay();

}

 // Called every frame
void ANPC::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void ANPC::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

}

void ANPC::Prox_Implementation(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, 
AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp,
int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
if (Cast<AAvatar>(OtherActor) == nullptr)
{
    return;
}
APlayerController* PController = GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController();
if (PController)
{
    AMyHUD * hud = Cast<AMyHUD>(PController->GetHUD());
    hud->addMessage(Message(NpcMessage, 5.0f, FColor::White));
    //name + FString(":") + message
}
}
```

Comment: You should probably head towards Unreal's dedicated forums and community, since stackOverflow is about general progarmming stuff, those kind of very specific soft-related issues may not find an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong specifically with the `hud->addMessage()` call. Is it possible `hud` is null or `PController->GetHUD()` is null?

Also, where is `ANPC::Prox()` defined? I notice it is refrenced here `ProxSphere->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &ANPC::Prox);`

Comment: Do you remember how you did the fix? I'm just curious.